# Setting up a server using Nginx?

Tags: nginx, debian

I have installed nginx on a linux box I have. The site is [here](http://ilan.duckdns.org). I can connect to it fine using the external IP from my laptop (on the same network as the server) but my friend in the US says he can't load the page. I tried an online vpn service and it returned an error that curl couldn't connect. How can I let others connect to my server too?
Here is my `/etc/nginx/available-sites/default` file contents:

```
server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name ilan.duckdns.org;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

I really don't know how to make this work and my google-fu isn't helping. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your router to redirect an external port to the internal linux server ip:port

Ex: 10.20.30.10:8080 (internet ip) ==> 192.168.0.12:80 (linux server on your network)

Comment: I have port forwarded port 80 from the internet to port 80 on my linux box already.

Comment: Have you tried other in ports?
80 can it be reserved / have conflicts?

Comment: I've similar file config for nginx on a raspberry, nothin special else, external port 8080 to network port 80.
Note it's a TCP port.

Don't forget restart your router :)